# How to INSERT all triples from an RDFlib graph into another repository without iterating through every triple?

Tags: python, sesame, rdflib, linked-data, sparqlwrapper

This question is related to [What URI to use for a Sesame repository while executing a SPARQL ADD query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457554/what-uri-to-use-for-a-sesame-repository-while-executing-a-sparql-add-query).

I'm trying to INSERT all triples from a Sesame repository into another (Dydra). There are a couple of ways to do it, such as using SERVICE clause or Dydra's GUI. However, Dydra restricts the use of SERVICE and I want an efficient way to insert the data programmatically. This is the code I have right now:

```
queryStringUpload = 'INSERT {?s ?p ?o} WHERE GRAPH %s {?s ?p ?o}' % dataGraph
    sparql = SPARQLWrapper(dydraSparqlEndpoint)
    sparql.setCredentials(key,key)
    sparql.setQuery(queryStringUpload)
    sparql.method = 'POST'
    sparql.query()
```

The code results in the following error:

```
client error: failed to parse after 'GRAPH' at offset 24 on line 1.
INSERT {?s ?p ?o} WHERE GRAPH [a rdfg:Graph;rdflib:storage [a rdflib:Store;rdfs:label 'IOMemory']]. {?s ?p ?o}
.
```

Basically, I understand that I'm incorrectly using string formatting. What is the correct way to execute the query?

One way to programmatically do this is by iterating through every triple in dataGraph and individually `INSERT`ing them. I've tried this approach. While the code works, not all of the data is ported. That's the reason I'm looking for a way to bulk port the data.

UPDATE 1

This is the code I tried for implementing the suggested answer:

```
    sesameURL = 'http://my.ip.ad.here:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/rep_name/statements'
payloadPOST = {
        'url': sesameURL,
        # 'account[login]':key,
        # 'account[password]':'',
        # 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrfToken_new,
        # 'next':'/',
        }   

        headersPOST = {
        'User-Agent': 'python',
        'Content-Type': 'application/n-quads',
        # 'Referer': dydraLogin,
        }

        paramsPOST = {
        'auth_token': key,
        #'url': sesameURL
        }
        # print payload

        try:
            q = s.post(dydraUrl,data=payloadPOST, params=paramsPOST, headers=headersPOST)
            print "q.text: " + q.text
            print "q_status_code: " + str(q.status_code)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
            print e
```

This is the error:

```
q_status_code: 400
```

However, if I comment out the 'url' attribute, I get this:

```
q_status_code: 201
```

Any ideas on how to resolve will be very helpful.

UPDATE 2

Now, irrespective of whether 'url' is under headersPOST or paramsPOST, I get the following as output:

```
q_status_code: 201
```

However, the data that I want to post doesn't get POSTed. How do I need to do differently?

Comment: You haven't shown what the actual value of your 'url' parameter is.

Comment: Added the value. I checked the URL. When typed into a browser, it returns a .rdf file with all the statements in the repository.

Comment: That looks correct. HTTP 201 is the normal response I'd expect on a POST request, so Dydra is not generating an error. I am not sure what's going wrong at this point. You could have a look in Sesame Server to check if you spot anything suspicious, but other than that I think you will need to get in touch with the Dydra team.

Comment: I checked with the folks at Dydra. They aren't sure how to solve this. 

For now, please ignore UPDATE 2. I consistently get a 400 error if I have 'url' as an attribute in payloadPOST. 

The folks at Dydra asked me to try cURL to see the response and headers. They don't appear to be sure that 'url' is the right attribute to use in the payload. 

I checked the docs but couldn't find a list of acceptable attributes that one can POST to Dydra.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not gonna bother answering why you get that syntax error on that SPARQL update, since it seems immaterial to what you actually want to know. I'm also not going to bother answering how to upload an RDFLib graph to Dydra, since that also seems immaterial to what you want to know. What I'll answer here is how you can upload data from a Sesame store to a Dydra store, programmatically, without having to iterate over all triples, and without use of the `SERVICE` clause.

Dydra's [REST API](http://docs.dydra.com/api/rest) is basically identical to the [Sesame REST API](http://rdf4j.org/sesame/2.8/docs/system.docbook?view), so most REST operations you can do on a Sesame store you can also execute on a Dydra store.

You can do a HTTP POST request to your Dydra store's REST API URL for statements: `repository/<ACCOUNT_ID>/<REPO_ID>/statements` (see [here in the Dydra docs](http://docs.dydra.com/api/rest#repository-statements) for more details). Add a parameter `url` which points to the URL of your source Sesame store URL for statements: (`repository/<REPO_ID>/statements`). Also make sure you specify a `Content-Type` HTTP header in your POST request that specifies the MIME-type of an RDF syntax format supported by Dydra (a good pick is something like TriG or N-Quads, since these formats support named graphs).

You don't even need RDFLib for any of this. Presumably you know how to do a simple HTTP request from Python, if not I'm sure there's examples aplenty as it's a fairly generic thing to do.

Comment: One small edit. The Dydra REST API URL for statements is http://dydra.com/<username>/repositories/<rep_name>/statements.

Comment: The updated docs are at https://github.com/dydra/http-api-tests. They recommend that one uses graph store protocol.